# Two-way binding not working in ContentControl bound to generic value

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, data-binding, user-controls

I am trying to build a user control which allows the editing of items in a list.
First I will show you the code I have and below the code I will explain my problem. If you want to reproduce the issue you can create a new project and copy all the code into it. I will include every class needed.

The code of the list the user control will be bound to:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace TestApplicationWPF
    {
      public class SettingList : List<ISetting>
      {
      }
    }
```

The interface ISetting:

```
namespace TestApplicationWPF
{
  public class ISetting
  {
    string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And the generic objects I write into the list:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestApplicationWPF
{
  public class Setting<T> : ISetting, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private T value;

    public T Value
    {
      get
      {
        return value;
      }
      set
      {
        this.value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Now the goal for the user control is to bind to an instance of SettingList and allow the user to edit the "Value"-Property of every "Setting"-instance in the list. For that the user control displays a specific control depending on the type of T in Setting. For example a String is shown in a Textbox and a DateTime-Value will be shown in a DatePicker.

The code for the user-control looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApplicationWPF.SettingEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplicationWPF"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:TypeOfConverter x:Key="TypeOfConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="TypedValueStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" IsReadOnly="true" Background="LightGray"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeOfConverter},Path=Value}" 
                     Value="String">
          <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}"                  
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="LvPluginSettings" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SettingEditor}}, Path=Settings, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Grid.Row="0">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Value" 
                          Width="Auto">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TypedValueStyle}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Name ="BtnSetValue" Grid.Row="1" Content="Set the value" Click="BtnSetValue_Click"/>
    <Button Name ="BtnGetValue" Grid.Row="2" Content="What's the value?" Click="BtnGetValue_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The .cs Code for the user-control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestApplicationWPF
{
  public partial class SettingEditor : UserControl
  {

    public SettingList Settings
    {
      get { return (SettingList)GetValue(PluginSettingsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(PluginSettingsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PluginSettingsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Settings",
                typeof(SettingList),
                typeof(SettingEditor),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
    );

    public SettingEditor()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnSetValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ((Setting<string>)Settings[0]).Value = "Different value now.";
    }

    private void BtnGetValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(((Setting<string>)Settings[0]).Value);
    }
  }
}
```

To determine the type of the "Value"-property of each item in the list I make use of a "TypeOfConverter". The converter looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestApplicationWPF
{
  public class TypeOfConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return (value == null) ? null : value.GetType().Name;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

And at last to be able to completely reproduce the issue I give you the MainWindow which uses the user control and it's ViewModel:
Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplicationWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplicationWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" />
  </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <local:SettingEditor Settings="{Binding Path=Settings}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace TestApplicationWPF
{
  public class MainWindowViewModel
  {
    public SettingList Settings { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
      Settings = new SettingList();
      Settings.Add(new Setting<string> { Name="Name of setting", Value = "HelloWorld" });
    }

  }
}
```

My problem is the binding of the Value-Property of a Setting-Instance. When I start the application it will show me the value perfectly fine. I get a textbox with "HelloWorld" in it. Also when the value changes in the background it will be updated to the textbox.
However when I set the cursor into the textbox, change the text to something else and leave the textbox, it will not be changed in the bound "Value"-Property. Also after I tried to edit the text in the textbox, changes made in the background do not affect the textbox anymore.

I would be deeply grateful if someone could help me with this. Even the smallest hint at what could be wrong would help me a lot.

Greetings,
Sven

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

In the user-control I have a ContentControl like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TypedValueStyle}" />
```

The DataTemplate for the control looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}"                  
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is the databinding. The Content of the ContentControl is bound to the Value-property in my object. The DataTemplate however is bound to the Content-property of the ContentControl. For the binding to work I needed to specificly set the binding of the control in the Data-Template to the Value-property.

The now working ContentControl looks like this:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding}" 
                            Content="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource TypedValueStyle}" />
```

And the DataTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>    
      <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.Value, Mode=TwoWay}"           
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO !

Here's an approach that leverages `ObservableCollection`, `DataTemplateSelector` and a few C# subtelties :D

[image]

**Notes:**

- Used an `ObservableCollection<T>` which notifies subscribers of changes in it
- Didn't bother with a `UserControl`, but with an `ItemsControl` instead
- `Setting` is purposefully abstract, enforcing `Setting<T>` usage
- **But** the observable collection holds `Setting` objects
- The items presenter uses a template selector which return the right template according the first generic type argument

Etc ... play with the code and see that it effectively works without being cumbersome :D

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var collection =
                new SettingCollection(new Setting[]
                {
                    new Setting<bool> {Name = "boolean"},
                    new Setting<string> {Name = "string"}
                });
            DataContext = collection;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var collection = (SettingCollection) DataContext;
            var setting = collection.OfType<Setting<bool>>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (setting != null)
            {
                setting.Value = !setting.Value;
            }
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var collection = (SettingCollection) DataContext;
            var setting = collection.OfType<Setting<string>>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (setting != null)
            {
                setting.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var collection = (SettingCollection) DataContext;
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    public sealed class SettingCollection : ObservableCollection<Setting>
    {
        public SettingCollection(List<Setting> list) : base(list)
        {
        }

        public SettingCollection(IEnumerable<Setting> collection) : base(collection)
        {
        }

        public SettingCollection()
        {
        }
    }

    public abstract class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private object _value;
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public object Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _value)) return;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public sealed class Setting<T> : Setting
    {
        private T _value;

        public new T Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _value)) return;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SettingTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var element = container as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null && item != null)
            {
                var type = item.GetType();
                var types = type.GenericTypeArguments;
                var type1 = types[0];

                if (type1 == typeof(bool))
                {
                    var findResource = element.FindResource("SettingBoolTemplate");
                    var dataTemplate = findResource as DataTemplate;
                    return dataTemplate;
                }

                if (type1 == typeof(string))
                {
                    var findResource = element.FindResource("SettingStringTemplate");
                    var dataTemplate = findResource as DataTemplate;
                    return dataTemplate;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <Button Content="Set first Setting&lt;bool&gt; to something" Click="Button1_Click" />
            <Button Content="Set first Setting&lt;string&gt; to something" Click="Button2_Click" />
            <Button Content="Debugger break" Click="Button3_Click"></Button>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="SettingBoolTemplate" DataType="local:Setting">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="SettingStringTemplate" DataType="local:Setting">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <local:SettingTemplateSelector x:Key="SettingTemplateSelector" />
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Setting">
                        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                                                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SettingTemplateSelector}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have found the problem in my code and posted an answer myself. I will still try out your code though because it looks a little nicer than mine.